# How make listview horizontally

Tags: android, xml

I'm confused about changing the vertical scroll listview to horizontal, I've looked for it in the forum, but nothing works, maybe someone can help, this is the script I found

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lvList"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and it didn't work.
and this is my original script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lvList"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recyclerview with horizontal  linear layout manager.